# Math for statistics

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, reference-request, self-learning

I suddenly got interested in machine learning so i began looking for where to start. After some research i found a [book about statistical learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/) which has to be a good place to begin. I'm about to take my second year in civil engineering and i don't know any matrix algebra. I found out that matrix algebra is a part of linear algebra. I searched for some videos and books on linear algebra and found quite a few of them. I don't know what source to pick so I would appreciate if someone would point me to a good source to learn linear algebra which would help me with mentioned book about statistical learning.

Answer (score 1):

See [Linear Algebra Done Right](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Linear-Algebra-Right-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/0387982582) by Sheldon Axler. There is also [a website](http://linear.axler.net).

There are many other references. This one is good but difficult. It makes sense if you already have some maths experience to give it a go, and then the beauty of the subject is clear from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't had any previous exposure to linear algebra, [Coding the matrix](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0615880991) is a nice introductory textbook. This book has the advantage that you also learn a lot of applications of linear algebra to computer science.

[Strang's classic book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0980232775) has more math, but it is still very accessible, and has video lectures through MIT OCW.